# Правильная работа с экранами приложения

Tags: android, java, шаблоны-проектирования

Этот вопрос, порожден прежде всего моим малым опытом в разработке для android и желанием не изобретать велосипед, опять. Предположим, что нужно сделать несколько экранов в приложении, пусть это будет начальный экран, или меню и около трех дополнительных экранов со всякой информацией, с тем условием что все они имеют разную структуру. Как принято решать подобную, типовую задачу? Возможно у вас есть собственное, полученное из опыта, решение? Буду рад его услышать.

Answer (score 1):

Все зависит от поставленной задачи! Одна активити и 3 фрагмента например.

Answer (score 0):

Гляньте: [Урок 21. Создание и вызов Activity](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/58-urok-21-sozdanie-i-vyzov-activity.html)

> Мы подобрались к очень интересной теме. На всех предыдущих уроках мы создавали приложения, которые содержали только один экран (Activity). Но если вы пользуетесь смартфоном с Android, то вы замечали, что экранов в приложении обычно больше. Если рассмотреть, например, почтовое приложение, то в нем есть следующие экраны: список аккаунтов, список писем, просмотр письма, создание письма, настройки и т.д.  Пришла и нам пора научиться создавать многоэкранные приложения.

Comment: В добавок, к посту, как разберётесь с активити, почитайте про фрагменты, сейчас на них все строится.

 [Фрагменты][1]


  [1]: http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/theory/fragments.php

Answer (score 0):

посмотри видео может поможет
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4_JLUkO7ydk&index=22&list=PLIU76b8Cjem7oSU18zTKNfsyzrmf3Zubl